# Populate data from joined table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table which has following structure

Employee Relation Table:

```
| FromEmployeeRelation | ToEmployeeRelation | CreatedAt | UpdatedAt |
+----------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2                    | 3                  | Date      | Date      |
```

Relation Table

```
| Id | EmployeeId | CreatedAt | UpdatedAt |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+
|2   | 5          | Date      | Date      |
|3   | 7          | Date      | Date      |
```

Id from Relation table in Foreign key for both FromEmployeeRelation and ToEmployeeRelation in Employee Relation Table

I am trying to get info from Employee Relation Table with actual employee id in the results

Result

```
| FromEmployeeId | ToEmployeeId | FromEmployeeRelation | ToEmployeeRelation  
+----------------+--------------+----------------------+-------------------
| 5              | 7            | 2                    | 3
```

From join I can get EmployeeId from one relation, but I am not sure how to get employee id for both the relations.

How can this be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select e1.EmployeeId  as FromEmployeeId ,
       e2.EmployeeId as ToEmployeeId ,
       er.FromEmployeeRelation,
       er.ToEmployeeRelation
 from emp_relation er
 inner join emp e1 on er.FromEmployeeRelation=e1.id
 inner join emp e2 on er.ToEmployeeRelation=e2.id
```

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebffe/2

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: joining a single table on two different columns, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a82e1c/1)

```
SELECT 
from_tbl.EmployeeId AS FromEmployeeId, 
to_tbl.EmployeeId AS ToEmployeeId, 
e.FromEmployeeRelation, 
e.ToEmployeeRelation
FROM EmployeeRelation e 
INNER JOIN Relation from_tbl ON e.FromEmployeeRelation = from_tbl.Id 
INNER JOIN Relation to_tbl ON e.ToEmployeeRelation = to_tbl.Id
```

Option 2: using sub queries, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a82e1c/5)

```
SELECT 
(SELECT from_tbl.EmployeeId FROM Relation from_tbl WHERE e.FromEmployeeRelation = from_tbl.Id) AS FromEmployeeId, 
(SELECT to_tbl.EmployeeId FROM Relation to_tbl WHERE e.ToEmployeeRelation = to_tbl.Id) AS ToEmployeeId, 
e.FromEmployeeRelation, 
e.ToEmployeeRelation
FROM EmployeeRelation e
```